# I need assistance with compacting my working PHP code

Tags: php

I was just working on a customer project and I am wondering if someone know how to make this code more compacter:

```
$box_size_unknown =
    $cart_item['f_box_L'] <= 0 || !$cart_item['f_box_L']
    ||
    $cart_item['f_box_H'] <= 0 || !$cart_item['f_box_H']
    ||
    $cart_item['f_box_D'] <= 0 || !$cart_item['f_box_D'];
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the purpose of this code. You have a variable which equals to some checks, instead to assign a value to it ... What's that all about?

Comment: What's the $box_size_unknown value you get from this code?

Comment: If your code works and you just want someone to review it/come with improvement suggestions, post it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @AngelDeykov - If any of those values (box dimensions) aren't properly set, the  result with be `true` (meaning that the box size is unknown)

Comment: This bit of code only contains a boolean telling you if the box size is known, or not. This boolean, and the size of the box, are probably used elsewhere. To "compact" the code it would be useful to see if it can be combined with that other code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a new member. Sorry if my answer is incomplete or wrong.

```
<?php

    function cars($ic){
        $cart_item = array('f_box_L','f_box_H','f_box_D');

        $cll = $cart_item[0];
        $clh = $cart_item[1];
        $cld = $cart_item[2];


        $box_size_unknown = $cll <= 0 || !$cll || $clh <= 0 || !$clh || 
        $cld <= 0 || !$cld;
        $ic = $box_size_unknown;
        echo $ic;
    }
     echo cars(0);
 ?>
```

Use the function I want to describe.